# Extending OWIN OAuth2.0 Password Grant With Security Questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I currently have OWIN/Katana in a WebApi2 application using OAuth2.0 password grants that I'd like to augment by adding those security questions you will see on bank sites, e.g. "What is your mother's cousin's childhood dog's name?"

What is the most efficient way to challenge the user with extra questions along with the typical password grant fields: user, password?

Does this necessary require implementing my own middleware and options to be integrated using IAppBuilder or is there a simpler approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server-side: from the `IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` notification, you can access the whole `IOwinContext` via `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext`, and thus, extract any custom parameter from the request form using `IOwinRequest.ReadFormAsync`.

On the client-side: you'll have to flow the security question answer with the `username` and `password` parameters. Complexity will directly depend on the hooks offered by your client.

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w&answer=boblemagnifique
```